# Excel true to text

Tags: excel, boolean, boolean-logic

[image]
This excel function return true while I want it to be "Sam"
couldn't fix it any ideas ?

```
=OR(AND(R2=TRUE),AND(S2=TRUE),AND(T2=TRUE,"Sam","max"),AND(U2=TRUE))
```

Comment: your formula does not seem ok.  Tell us what you want to do.

Comment: `AND()` and `OR()` functions operate on equality statements inside their `()`, like this: `AND( R2=TRUE, S2=TRUE, OR(T2=TRUE, T2="Sam", T2="max"), U2=TRUE)`.

Comment: as you see i got 4 cells on of them are true, i want each cell has a replace from True to text

Comment: no no i have one true value, i want the true value replaced to a text.

Comment: ok i added a screenshot

Comment: YES exactly I want to replace true

Comment: but i have 3 other cells with other text

Comment: Sir, that is why i am saying show something what you have and what you need, the image which you have shown is not proper, screenshot with the expected output

Comment: As you see in the image, I have 4 Boolean cells right ? i want if any of them true it will be replaced with a specific text.

Comment: Ahaa i understood so you want to replace the cells showing from Q2 To U2 to a text if anyone of them is showing `TRUE`, i am not sure how its done with `Excel Formula` you need VBA then, could you edit your tag as `VBA` and have you written any code yet

Comment: Wrap it in an `IF` function and specify the True part and the FalsePart arguments?

Comment: Like `IF(OR(R2,D2,T2),"Sam","Max")`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Sir, OP wants to replace the cells if any one of them showing as `TRUE`, will it be possible with a formula!

Comment: I want different values for each cell that show true

Comment: @Mayukh with "Sam" in the True part and "Max" in the False part of an IF function, you get "Sam" when it's true and "Max" when it's false...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon sir, thats correct, even i had suggested that only, but deleted the same, since OP wants to replace the cells where it finds a `TRUE`

Comment: In that case OP needs clarifications, ...a function can only return a value, not modify other cells. Maybe a macro then, but not possible to answer without clarifying the problem. I'm not seeing why it can't be a function if OP function evaluated to a Boolean, assuming the function is in the cell that ultimately needs to have the desired value.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Sir, absolutely even i said that, if you go through the thread, and might be OP is not familiar with VBA